# How to insert a record and return the primary key to update the foreign key in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, postgresql-9.4

I need to add value to a foreign key column in a table (`table1`). For this I have to create a new record in another table (`table2`) and return the handle to update the column with foreign key in the first table (`table1`).

Also, when I insert the new record in `table2`, I need a value contained in `table1` for one of the columns in `table2`.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table2_id = (INSERT INTO table2 (id, anumber, atimestamp, atext) 
                VALUES (nextval('seqtable2'), 0, NOW()::TIMESTAMP, table1.anumber::TEXT) 
                RETURNING id );
```

I believe that with the above script (even not working) it is possible to understand the problem. I wrote in the simplest and most summarized way.

I'm looking for a solution for PostgreSQL 9.4, but if there are alternatives to later versions, I'd like to know as well.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pg/psql as follows:

```
DO
$updatecode$
DECLARE
  i int;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table2 (id, anumber, atimestamp, atext) 
  VALUES (nextval('seqtable2'), 0, NOW()::TIMESTAMP, 2::TEXT) 
  RETURNING id into i;

  UPDATE table1 SET table2_id = i WHERE ...

END;
$updatecode$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Edit**:

I had to add a loop because I needed to change multiple records. Another change was to be able to use a value of `table1` in the `atext` column while inserting the record into `table2`.

```
DO 
$insertforupdate$
DECLARE 
    tbl1 table1%ROWTYPE;
    tbl2_id INTEGER;
BEGIN 

    FOR tbl1 IN SELECT * FROM table1 
    LOOP 

        INSERT INTO table2 (id, anumber, atimestamp, atext) 
        VALUES (nextval('seqtable2'), 0, NOW()::TIMESTAMP, tbl1.anumber::TEXT) 
        RETURNING id INTO tbl2_id;

        UPDATE table1 SET table2_id = tbl2_id WHERE id = tbl1.id;

    END LOOP;

END;
$insertforupdate$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```